# How to add an endpoint for my custom post type? /wp-json/wp/v2/posts is working but it didn't in the custom post

Tags: api, rest-api, endpoints

```
function create_api_posts_meta_field() {

// register_rest_field ( 'name-of-post-type', 'name-of-field-to-return', array-of-callbacks-and-schema() )
register_rest_field( 'post', 'post-meta-fields', array(
       'get_callback'    => 'get_post_meta_for_api',
       'schema'          => null,
    )
);

// register_rest_field ( 'name-of-post-type', 'name-of-field-to-return', array-of-callbacks-and-schema() )
register_rest_field( 'achievement', 'post-meta-fields', array(
       'get_callback'    => 'get_post_meta_for_api',
       'schema'          => null,
    )
);function get_post_meta_for_api( $object ) {
//get the id of the post object array
$post_id = $object['id'];

//return the post meta
return get_post_meta( $post_id );}
```

Please the code above! Tia

Comment: Are you trying to add an endpoint to retrieve your posts or add meta to the results? You question and code are about 2 different things.

Comment: Im trying to create an endpoint that will retrieve/show all posts in my custom post type. And I also want to filter it by showing the id and the title(rendered) only.

Answer (score 1):

The "register_rest_field" function will add and handle data update for a given endpoint, looks like it's not what you are looking for.

The register_post_type() function accepts a "show_in_rest" and "rest_base" params if you want to use a custom slug for the endpoint:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

By default it uses the WP_REST_Posts_Controller class to handle the methods (get, update, delete content), this means that you can refer to the following documentation:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/

There are already a few parameters you can pass for filtering (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts), but if you want to alter the results/order returned on the GET method to suit your custom needs, you have to pass a custom class for the REST controller param("rest_controller_class") in the register_post_type() function.

Comment: Thank you for this. I just put ('show_in_rest'       => true) on my register_post_type and it works. Thank you again.

About filtering the response on my endpoint, I really cant find a solution where I can see only the id and the title of the post. Is there a way that i can use a request like /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100 for filtering the id and title?

Comment: Hi @RonOgrimen, not sure I do understand your question but if the goal is to show only id and title within the REST API response for that endpoint, you should have to use a custom class controller, you can take the posts one as a base(WP_REST_Posts_Controller) and use it for your custom post type. I'd recommend to check the methods for that class if you want to return a custom response and custom sort.

Comment: Did you try the include param?:

/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100&include=1,2,3,4

also the search, order and order by can help:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments

Comment: Thank you @pabamato, I really appreciate it. Right now I need only to show posts by the current date. Is there a request like that? ?search= is not working

Comment: Did you try using "after" and "before" parameters? You have to pass an ISO 8601 date string as parameter, you can use WordPress built in time function for time formatting: https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time